# Dash datatable with expandable/collapsable rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, plotly-dash, plotly-dash-datatable

Similar to qtTree, I would like to have a drill down on a column of a datatable. I guess this is better illustrated with an example. Assume we have a dataframe with three columns: Country, City, Population like:

```
Country    City        Population
USA        New-York    19MM
China      Shanghai    26MM
China      Beijing     20MM
USA        Los Angeles 12MM
France     Paris       11MM
```

Is there a way to present this data ideally in a dash-plotly datatable as follows:

```
Country    City        Population
+USA                   31MM
 /---->    New-York    19MM
 /---->    Los Angeles 12MM
+China                 46MM
 /---->    Shanghai    26MM
 /---->    Beijing     20MM
+France                11MM
 /---->    Paris       11MM
```

The grouping Country/City would be expandle (or maybe hidden/shown upon click on the row -?-). At the country level, the population would be the sum of its constituents and the City level, the population would be the one from that city.

The library dash_treeview_antd allows for treeview representation but I don't know how to include the population column for instance. Maybe there is a simpler way by doing the groupby in pandas first and then having a callback to hide/show the currentrow selection/clicked?

### Edit:

I have been playing around with `.groupby` in pandas and the ['`active_cell`' Dash DataTable property](https://dash.plotly.com/datatable/reference) in the callback.

```
def defineDF():
    df = pd.DataFrame({'Country': ['USA', 'China', 'China', 'USA', 'France'],
                   'City': ['New-York', 'Shanghai', 'Beijing', 'Los Angeles', 'Paris'],
                   'Population': [19, 26, 20, 12, 11],
                   'Other': [5, 3, 4, 11, 43]})
    df.sort_values(by=['Country', 'City'], inplace=True)
    return df

def baseDF():
    df = pd.DataFrame({'Country': ['USA', 'China', 'China', 'USA', 'France'],
                   'City': ['New-York', 'Shanghai', 'Beijing', 'Los Angeles', 'Paris'],
                   'Population': [19, 26, 20, 12, 11],
                   'Other': [5, 3, 4, 11, 43]})
    df.sort_values(by=['Country', 'City'], inplace=True)
    f = {'Population': 'sum', 'Other': 'sum'}
    cols = ['Country']
    return df.groupby(cols).agg(f).reset_index()

startDF = baseDF()

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div(html.H6("Country/City population"), style={"text-align":"center"}),
    html.Hr(),
    dash_table.DataTable(
        id='table',
        columns=[{'name': i, 'id': i} for i in startDF.columns],
        data = startDF.to_dict('records'),
        selected_rows=[],
        filter_action='native',
    )
])

@app.callback([
Output('table', 'data'),
Output('table', 'columns')
],
[
    Input('table', 'active_cell')
],
[
    State('table', 'data'),
    State('table', 'columns')
],
)
    def updateGrouping(active_cell, power_position, power_position_cols):
    if active_cell is None:
        returndf = baseDF()
    elif active_cell['column'] == 0:
        returndf = defineDF()
    else:
        returndf = baseDF()

    cols = [{'name': i, 'id': i} for i in returndf.columns]

    return [returndf.to_dict('records'), cols]
```

I am getting there. At start I only display the country column; it would be nice to have the column City there too but with empty values. Then once the user clicks on a country, only show the Cities for that country (and the corresponding Population/Other columns while the rest of the table is unchanged). I am not using `current_df` nor `current_df_cols` in the callback yet, but I suspect they might become handy. Maybe I can filter the country column based on active cell?

Comment: I have posted a possible solution leveraging the Plotly Dash `data_table` conditional dropdowns functionality, and demonstrate how a table can be dynamically updated with callbacks triggered by changes to the dropdown. This could be extended in many imaginable ways - for example, if you wanted to display something closer to the expanded tree you describe, you could perhaps add a dropdown option "All", and modify the callback function to add additional `row`'s to the output `rows` parameter. Etc. The callback is triggered upon any interaction at all with the table!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Dynamic Python Dash app `data_table` with row-based dropdowns triggering callbacks

This is a little tricky, but hopefully the following example might help achieve what you are attempting. The main drawback is probably the requirement for hard-coding the `dropdown_conditional` parameter (although, you probably wouldn't want to have more columns for a user to interact with then would be prohibitive to hard-code!). So, I think this should provide you with the general functional gist sufficient for you to further customize it as needed.

```py
import pandas as pd

from collections import OrderedDict

from dash import Dash, Input, Output, State, dcc, html, callback
from dash.exceptions import PreventUpdate
from dash import dash_table


start_df = pd.DataFrame(
    OrderedDict([("Country", ["USA", "China", "France"])])
)
start_df["City"] = ""
start_df["Population"] = [31, 46, 11]

population_df = pd.DataFrame(
    OrderedDict(
        [
            ("Country", ["USA", "China", "China", "USA", "France"]),
            (
                "City",
                ["New-York", "Shanghai", "Beijing", "Los Angeles", "Paris",],
            ),
            ("Population", [19, 26, 20, 12, 11]),
        ]
    )
)

app = Dash(__name__)


app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        html.Div(
            html.H1("Country/City population"), style={"text-align": "center"}
        ),
        html.Hr(),
        dash_table.DataTable(
            id="table",
            columns=[
                {"id": "Country", "name": "Country",},
                {"id": "City", "name": "City", "presentation": "dropdown",},
                {"id": "Population", "name": "Population (Total [M])"},
            ],
            data=start_df.to_dict("records"),
            editable=True,
            dropdown_conditional=[
                {
                    "if": {
                        "column_id": "City",  # skip-id-check
                        "filter_query": '{Country} eq "China"',
                    },
                    "options": [
                        {"label": i, "value": i}
                        for i in population_df[
                            population_df.Country == "China"
                        ].City.values
                    ],
                },
                {
                    "if": {
                        "column_id": "City",  # skip-id-check
                        "filter_query": '{Country} eq "USA"',
                    },
                    "options": [
                        {"label": i, "value": i}
                        for i in population_df[
                            population_df.Country == "USA"
                        ].City.values
                    ],
                },
                {
                    "if": {
                        "column_id": "City",  # skip-id-check
                        "filter_query": '{Country} eq "France"',
                    },
                    "options": [
                        {"label": i, "value": i}
                        for i in population_df[
                            population_df.Country == "France"
                        ].City.values
                    ],
                },
            ],
            style_cell={
                "fontSize": "0.8rem",
                "whiteSpace": "normal",
                "padding": "3px",
                "textOverflow": "ellipsis",
                "textAlign": "center",
                "maxWidth": "300px",
            },
            style_header={
                "fontWeight": "500",
                "fontSize": "0.8rem",
                "cursor": "pointer",
            },
        ),
        html.Div(id="table_container"),
    ]
)


@callback(
    Output("table", "data"),
    Input("table", "data_timestamp"),
    State("table", "data"),
)
def update_table(timestamp, rows):
    print(timestamp)
    for row in rows:
        country = row["Country"]
        city = row["City"]
        if city == "" or city is None:
            print(country)
            population = start_df.set_index("Country").loc[country][
                "Population"
            ]
            print(population)
            row["Population"] = population
        elif city in population_df[["City"]].values:
            print(city)
            population = population_df.set_index("City").loc[city][
                "Population"
            ]
            print(population)
            row["Population"] = population

    return rows


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(start_df)
    app.run(debug=True)
```

gives the following app reactivity:
[image: Dash app with interactive row-based dropdowns triggering callbacks]

The `print()` functions were used/are included for debugging purposes. E.g., providing this to stdout in the terminal when running app:

```bash
Dash is running on http://127.0.0.1:8050/

 * Serving Flask app "app" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
  Country City  Population
0     USA               31
1   China               46
2  France               11
None
USA
31
China
46
France
11
1690628030839
New-York
19
China
46
France
11
1690628033725
Los Angeles
12
China
46
France
11
1690628035972
USA
31
China
46
France
11
1690628038742
USA
31
Shanghai
26
France
11
1690628041373
USA
31
Shanghai
26
Paris
11
1690628043825
Los Angeles
12
Shanghai
26
Paris
11
1690628046159
Los Angeles
12
China
46
Paris
11
1690628047975
Los Angeles
12
China
46
France
11
1690628050125
USA
31
China
46
France
11
```

where you can see every interaction with the data table in the app in browser triggers first a printing of the timestamp recorded for that interaction, and then the changes which become rendered in the `data_table` triggered by the dropdown components in the "City" column.